# Get local Windows user name from a SID with C++

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, sid

If I have a list of Windows account SIDs (strings like "S-1-5-21-16217043-3088031003-1644254475-1001") how can I get the name of Windows user accounts from them (stuff like "John Doe") using C++ and WinAPIs?

Comment: [LookupAccountSid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379166(v=vs.85).aspx) may be helpful.

Comment: I tried it and it returns ERROR_NONE_MAPPED.

Comment: ...after [ConvertStringSidToSid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376402.aspx).

Comment: Have you tried a well-known SID to ensure you're actually invoking the function(s) properly, because this has always worked for me so long as the SID owner still has an account on the system. Otherwise, the SID is all you're gonna get.

Comment: I made mistake. Sorry. Read my explanation below...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

See these WINAPI functions:

- [`ConvertStringSidToSid()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376402%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), to convert the account SID strings to a [`SID`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379594%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) that is required as an argument to,
- [`LookupAccountSid()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379166%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: As stated above, LookupAccountSid returns ERROR_NONE_MAPPED.

Comment: Oops, sorry. I copied and pasted the SID from the old document. It was just a couple digits off. Other than that your method works. Thanks.