# Get Username string from RPC binding handle

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, rpc

**How can one get a client's Username given an `RPC_BINDING_HANDLE` without side effects?**

I know that I can call `RpcImpersonateClient` to impersonate a client on server's thread and then get SID which could be used to [get the Username string](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13186633/9363996).
But this function changes global state. This can be reverted immediatelly by calling `RpcRevertToSelfEx`, but I don't know about the possible overhead of calling these functions. I just need to log the client's Username, and changing global state just for that seems to be heavyweight.

Comment: Are you looking for RpcServerInqCallAttributes ? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/rpcasync/nf-rpcasync-rpcserverinqcallattributesw

Comment: @SimonMourier maaaybe. Does `RPC_CALL_ATTRIBUTES_V2_A::ClientPrincipalName` yield username though?

Comment: It's the client principal name.... It depends on what exactly you mean by "username". You should try it in your case see if it's what you expect

Comment: @SimonMourier I expect to get the name of the impersonated user the RPC binding was created for. `RpcImpersonateClient` is said to impersonate *the client indicated by this handle*. So after calling it and retreiving a SID from a Thread Token I can get the "Username" ("Admin", for example). Unfortunatelly I don't know what "principal name" mean

Comment: @SimonMourier I tried. Calling `RpcServerInqCallAttributes` with `RPC_QUERY_CLIENT_PRINCIPAL_NAME` flag returned empty `ClientPrincipalName`. However the Client side **did** set up `AuthIdentity` via `RpcBindingSetAuthInfo`. What might be the reason for it?

Comment: It's not event necessary to use RpcBindingSetAuthInfo to get client principal. It also depends on the protocol sequence. For example with `ncalrpc`, client principal is automatically filled.

Comment: @SimonMourier *protocol sequence* - does it mean I have to call some other function prior to a query? Like `RpcBindingInqAuthClient` maybe?